# Is it ok to host my aspnetdb database on the webserver?

Tags: sql-server, security

We are about to launch our first internet asp.net application (as opposed to plenty of intranet ones).

An old win 2003 server has been commissioned to host this tiny asp.net site that utilizes an aspnetdb SQL SERVER database for user and role memberships etc.

I was originally going to host it on our main live sql server database but have found that this is only configured for win auth only (not SQL authentication). As the webserver is sensibly outside our corporate domain and firewall I can't use windows authentication so need to provide another sql server (express) instance to host this one database.

From a security perspective is it ok to put the sql server database on the same machine as the webserver? Can it be easily hacked?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, it is a best practice to only have the front ends outside of the firewall. It sounds like with your setup that isn't doable quickly or easily. I would question if there are ways you could have had the external domain talk to the internal domain with limited trust so you could use Windows Auth still.

Short of that though - I presume you are ONLY hosting the Aspnetdb there. It certainly isn't best but you can take some steps to minimize risk:

- Disable the actual SA account - use a different account with SA rights for your SA needs
- Minimize the rights of the account that ASP will use to talk to SQL - give it just the minimum rights it needs.
- Ensure that only the ports necessary to be seen by the outside world are open (yes you are not in your corporate firewall, but hopefully your servers don't just sit completely on the outside....) so just open 80, 443, etc.
- Change the default port of SQL Server (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938)

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I am only accessing SQL server via shared memory (because iis and sql are on the same box) and TCP/IP is disabled then do I still need to change the default port?

Comment: Nope and that is one more way to help lock you down a bit more. Still not as nice as putting SQL behind the internal firewall but you are taking steps to minimize your risk.